# How to write binary correct into file and prove it?

Tags: java

For my Java program I get a list of byte Arrays which I need to write into a file. What I've tried before was

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("file.out");
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

bw.write(new String(data));
bw.flush();
```

With data being a byte[] from the list.
Because I'm converting it to a String I assume I loose the correctness of the binary.

So I'm trying it with FileOutputStream now.

```
File myFile = new File("file.out");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

bos.write(data);
bos.flush();
```

Also with data being a byte[] from the list.

My question is, how can I check now if my written file is really binary correct. If I would read each line of the file as byte[] and compare it to the input would it be completly the same?

Comment: Have you considered a unit test?

Comment: Yes, only binary files don't have lines, read the whole file into a byte array and compare them, they should be the same.

Comment: If you are a linux user you can see the data of binary file using xxd command

Comment: Calculate and compare md5 hashes for both input and file content?

Answer (score 0):

To write your array to file:

```
List<byte[]> list = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
out.writeObject(list);
```

Then to read your array back from the same file:

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
List<byte[]> byteList = (List<byte[]>) in.readObject();
```

Note - this doesn't include disposing of streams, exception handling etc